# 0 tests runned while using Allure

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, allure

```
PS C:\Users\MARSHAL\Desktop\Framework\untitled> mvn clean test
```

After running these command i see that:

```
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

What can be the reason?

```
public class AllureReportUITest {
   private static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\MARSHAL\\Desktop\\Framework\\untitled\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@Test
@Step("UI Test")
public void openLoginPage() throws InterruptedException {
    // Step 1
    driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000");

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("log"));
    element.click();
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Sign up')]"));
    element1.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // Step 2
    String generatedUsername = random();

    WebElement usernameInput = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
    usernameInput.sendKeys(generatedUsername);

    String generatedPassword = random();
    WebElement passwordInput = driver.findElement(By.name("password1"));
    passwordInput.sendKeys(generatedPassword);

    WebElement passwordConfirm = driver.findElement(By.name("password2"));
    passwordConfirm.sendKeys(generatedPassword);

    WebElement registerButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Register']"));
    registerButton.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // Step 3
    WebElement spanElement = driver.findElement(By.id("un"));
    String actualText = spanElement.getText();
    String expectedText = generatedUsername;
    Assert.assertEquals(actualText, expectedText, "unexpected message");
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // Step 4
    WebElement hpclick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'HP')]"));
    hpclick.click();
    WebElement hpLaptop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Ноутбук HP Pavilion 14-dv0047ua')]"));
    hpLaptop.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // Step 5
    WebElement comment = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Write your message here..']"));
    comment.sendKeys("Good Product");
    comment.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Attachments
    takeScreenshot();
    attachHtmlCode("<html><body>HTML Code</body></html>");
    attachRequest("Request");
    attachResponse("Response");
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

private String random() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8).replace("-", "");
}

@Attachment("Screenshot")
public static byte[] takeScreenshot() {
    return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}

@Attachment("HTML Code")
public static ByteArrayInputStream attachHtmlCode(String htmlCode) {
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlCode.getBytes());
}

@Attachment("Request")
public static String attachRequest(String request) {
    return request;
}

@Attachment("Response")
public static String attachResponse(String response) {
    return response;
}
```

}                                                                                                      ---testing.xml---

```
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="End-to-End Test Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="AllureReportTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="AllureReport.AllureReportUITest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

---pom.xml---

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Archetype - untitled</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.36.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.32</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          <argLine>
            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
          </argLine>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>listener</name>
              <value>io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

[image: My structure of files]

Maybe i'm doing something wrong but i don't know what and could you help me out with this and tell me what should or change or how should i run it properly etc